# Cocoapod - Creating a new cocoapod with a dependency of another cocoapod fails

Tags: ios, swift, dependencies, cocoapods

I am creating a new cocoapod, and want to include another cocoapod as a dependency.

I added the necessary line to the podspec:

```
  s.dependency 'Locksmith', '~> 2.0.8'
```

But trying to import it in my class gives me an error:

```
No such module 'Locksmith'
```

Is there another step required to make dependencies work within my pod classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

Have to run `pod install` on the `Example` folder.